# wp_get_object_terms returns only Uncategorized on first publish

Tags: posts, taxonomy

I would like to get all assigned categories of a post once it's published with the `save_post` hook:

```
add_action( 'save_post', function( $post_id, $post, $update = null ) {

    if ( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) {;
        $categories = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'category' );

        ...
    }

},10 ,3 );
```

When I save the post for the **first time** `$categories` contain always the "Uncategorized" category.
Once I update the post (without changing any taxonomy) it contains the selected categories.

`$categories` on first save:

```
Array(

[0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 1
        [name] => Uncategorized
        [slug] => uncategorized
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 1
        [taxonomy] => category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 2
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

)

`$categories` on post update:

```
Array (

[0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 2
        [name] => My Category
        [slug] => my-category
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
        [taxonomy] => category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 1
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

)

I'm sure this is not the expected behavior but I can repeat this with every version of the block editor. WP 4.9 works as expected and shows all selected categories even on the first publish.

**EDIT:**

Looks WordPress 5.6 introduced [`wp_after_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_after_insert_post/) because of this. More on that [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_after_insert_post/).

So how could I get this to work for WP 5.0-5.5?

Comment: WP has a default category - it's selectable in the admin/settings/writing section - it would make sense that this is assigned to all new posts at some point - perhaps you need to work with a later hook ( or priority ) once the tax data has been saved correctly?

Comment: Yes, it would make sense if I didn't select any other category. I wonder if this is a bug as the behavior is as expected with the classic editor.

Comment: I doubt the editor used has an effect on this, and as far as I know, the addition of Gutenberg to Core did not change this underlying functionality.

Comment: Actually the REST API is to blame: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45114

Comment: "So how could I get this to work for WP 5.0-5.5?" Having read through the Trac ticket you posted, I think your options are a) update WordPress to 5.6, or b) (if you can't update) install & the Classic Editor plugin. Updating is the preferable option.

Comment: It should work for all these versions as I can't force customers to update. I guess it will be some workaround for these versions